# Azure VM SQL Server using Windows authentication from another Azure VM ASP.NET application

Tags: sql-server, azure

Currently I have two Azure VM's, one for the ASP.NET application (VM1) and another with SQL Server 2017 (VM2).

At the moment, the application on VM1 connects to VM2's SQL Server using SQL Server authentication, but now I want to change it to Windows authentication. I found this on the Azure website about how to connect:

> Virtual networks also enables you to join your Azure VMs to a domain. This is the only way to use Windows authentication to SQL Server. The other connection scenarios require SQL Server authentication with user names and passwords.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sqlclassic/virtual-machines-windows-classic-sql-connect

But there is also a website forum ask to use Azure Active Directory domain in order to achieve this.

I am confused regarding this, can anyone help me with a description how to connect my VM1 application to VM2 SQL Server using Windows authentication?

Comment: Virtual networks is connectivity only. To connect using windows authentication your VM's need to be "domain joined". That means you need a domain controller somewhere. This is not going down the cloud path.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid thanks for the comment , yeah finally i understand how the stuff work after the watched this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OQjK4gC89Xc

Comment: @rasu do you have any other concerns? Is that solved your problem?